# How do I link my sons phone back in Find My iPhone

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Son lost his phone so I went to Find My iPhone. I locked his phone then accidentally removed it from Find My iPhone. How can I link it back?

Answer (score 1):

If someone who got your son's phone and remove it from Find My Phone list, I'm not sure if you can add it back to the list again. I lost my iPhone 6 last October and my phone has been removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are both in the same family (iCloud Settings towards the top), and both of you have Find my iPhone turned on.